# I am getting this error while importing database on hosting server. but it is working on local server

Tags: mysql, database, export, hosting

It is different thing because it is working in localhost fine but not in online phpmyadmin. it is giving this error online. offline localhost is working.
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `NOTIFICATIONS` (
  `NOTIFICATION_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `MESSAGE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `VISITED` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `DATE` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NOTIFICATION_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'DATE'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to export your sql file instead of copy pasting?

Comment: yup exported from localhost and tried too. it is giving same error.